# Android - Fetching XML Data from web(Using AsyncTask) and Progressbar related problem

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am fetching an XML data from the web using HTTP GET/POST.
Right now i have done it in simple way (i.e. without threaed).

According to the below link, i tried to implement it with Progress bar dialog with Thread
http://www.ceveni.com/2009/09/sample-progress-bar-dialog-in-android.html

But how do i come to know about the finish time  of fetching XML from the web.(i.e. **what should be the sleep time and also when to dismiss the progress bar dialog box**)

Let me clear more about my problem =>  In activity,when the user click on "Fetch data" button,
the "Progress bar" dialog box should be appeared and it should be disappear only when the fetching is completed
successfully.

I think this can be done with "**AsyncTask**" but dont know how to use that concept for this problem.

So how do i do it ?

Comment: You are right, `ASyncTask` is what you are looking for. Some points to start: - http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html (guess you know that :D ) - some short tutorial: http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public  void onClick() {
        new FetchTask(context).execute(null);
    }

    public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object > {

    private ProgressDialog dlg;
    private Context ctx;

    public FetchTask(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        dlg.setMessage("Loading....");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        dlg.dismiss();
        if ( result instanceof Exception ) {
            // show error message
        } else {
            // display data
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
        // String rawData = doPost("yourUrl");
        // XMLTree data = yourParser.parse(rawData);
        // return data;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            return e;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: got the idea ,but where you have written about showing dialog as soon as the button clicked ?

Comment: yourBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { new FetchTask(context).execute(null); } } );

Comment: ya it is there, but i am not getting anywhere "dialog.show()" or "showdialog()" method

Comment: The showDialog should be in `onPreExecute()` and the dismiss should be in the `onPostExecute()`